# BeautifulSoup not extracting div properly

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

BeautifulSoup is not extracting the div I want properly. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the html:

```
                <div id='display'>
                      <div class='result'>
                           <div>text0 </p></div>
                           <div>text1</div>
                           <div>text2</div>
                       </div>
                  </div>
```

And here is my code:

```
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "result"})
print(div)
```

I am seeing this:

```
<div class="result">
<div>text0 </div></div>
```

What I am expecting is this:

```
<div class="result">
<div>text0</div>
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
</div>
```

This works as expected if I remove the `</p>` tag. In other words, the `</p>` tag seems to be throwing the parser off.

### Edit:

This works as expected on Python 2.7.12, beautifulsoup4 version 4.5.1. But does not work on Python 3.6.4, beautifulsoup4 version 4.7.1. Not sure if the culprit is python version or bs4 version (more likely).

Can someone please help?

Comment: why did you not have the open tag `<p>` in the html ?

Comment: Its not my html. I am trying to scrape html written by someone else. I know that there is no opening ```<p>``` tag. But BeautifulSoup should only be worried about ```</div>``` isn't it? Anyway, is there a way around this?

Comment: Just change `div = soup.find("div", {"class": "result"})` to `div = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"})` and it should work.

Comment: Running your code, I do get what you would like to get. There is some sort of incompleteness/inconsistency in your question.

Comment: What is your BeautifulSoup version on python3?

Comment: @sentence beautifulsoup4==4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem using select

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''
<div id='display'>
                      <div class='result'>
                           <div>text0 </p></div>
                           <div>text1</div>
                           <div>text2</div>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  '''
soup = bs(html)
soup.select('.result')
```

Comment: I ran the exact program, with ```print(soup.select('.result'))``` as the last line. It printed ```[<div class="result">
<div>text0 </div></div>]```  I guess at this point, based on your and @sentence comment above, it looks like this might be an issue with my particular setup. I am on Python 3.6.4.

Comment: Just ran the exact same program on Python 2.7.12, it printed ```[<div class="result">\n<div>text0 </div>\n<div>text1</div>\n<div>text2</div>\n</div>]``` which is what I want.