# BeautifulSoup prematurely cutting off div when encountering a closing tag without an accompanying open tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm having a similar problem to the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471247/beautifulsoup-not-extracting-div-properly), but that question never received a response for Python 3.

I am trying to scrape a page that often uses a custom closing tag in the middle of the divs I'm looking for without an accompanying opening tag, and it's causing BeautifulSoup to see that as the end of the div.

The HTML looks like...

```
<div class="eligible-promo">
    <h4>Promo Header</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>items here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item here</li>
    </ul>

    </productlist:g047:g0471>

    <h4>Different Promo Header</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>items here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item here</li>
    </ul>

    </productlist:g047:g0472>

</div>
```

When I run `soup.find('div', {'class': 'eligible-promo'})`, BeautifulSoup is returning...

```
<div class="eligible-promo">
    <h4>Promo Header</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>items here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I didn't write this HTML and I have no idea what the `</productlist>` tag is or why it doesn't have an accompanying opening tag. All I know is BeautifulSoup is replacing it with a `</div>` tag and I don't want it to. I'm using Python version 3.8.1 and BeautifulSoup version 4.8.2.

Comment: What exactly is your issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thoughts, I think what you want is `find_all()` not `find()` because running this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """
<div class="eligible-promo">
    <h4>Promo Header</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>items here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item here</li>
    </ul>

    </productlist:g047:g0471>

    <h4>Different Promo Header</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>items here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item here</li>
    </ul>

    </productlist:g047:g0472>

</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find_all("div", {"class": "eligible-promo"})
print(soup)
```

Gives this:

```
[<div class="eligible-promo">
<h4>Promo Header</h4>
<ul>
<li>items here</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>item here</li>
</ul>

<h4>Different Promo Header</h4>
<ul>
<li>items here</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>item here</li>
</ul>

</div>]
```

So, there are all the tags within that div. There's no need to worry about this *scary* **void elements** or **singelton tags** that don't require a closing tag to be valid.

These elements are usually ones that either stand alone on the page ​or where the end of their contents is obvious from the context of the page itself.

There are plenty of those in the `HTML`. Like `<img>`, for example...

EDIT:

I've installed your version of `BeautifulSoup == 4.8.2` and now I can reproduce the issue. I guess, it's time to upgrade. The code works as expected with version `4.9.3`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result with find_all. BeautifulSoup is still cutting off everything after that `</productlist>` tag.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing when I try... https://i.imgur.com/V3cfgLB.png

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Where do you run this code? You sure you don't have another instance of `soup` anywhere else defined?

Comment: The test I did in the screenshot above was in Jupyter. I ran the same test in IDLE and PyCharm and got the same results in both. The only code I'm running in these tests is an exact copy/paste of what's in your response. Definitely no other instances of anything else running. What version of Python and BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: I've written this code in PyCharm with a `venv` with Python 3.8.6 and the latest version of BeautifulSoup 4.9.3. I have *no* idea how come you're getting only a part of the div. As a matter of fact, even with `find()` on the very sample that's in your question gives me the correct result *without* the void element. Is there any chance you can share the actual page you're scraping?

Comment: Indeed it was. I've upgraded to version 4.9.3 and am no longer having the issue.

Comment: In case anyone else ever comes across this thread having the same problem, and like me also has a problem upgrading BeautifulSoup, running `pip install bs4 --upgrade` won't work because bs4 is just a dummy wrapper that's always on version 0.0.1. You have to run `pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade`.